# Python: Last character of user input

Tags: python, input

I was just wondering how I could find out what the last character of the user input was using Python. I need to know whether it was an S or not. Thanks in advance.....

Comment: `user_input.endswith('S')` or `user_input[-1:] == 'S'`

Comment: Please edit your question to include how you are gathering users input. Are you using raw_input() ?

Comment: what @falsetru said, or user_input[-1] if the input is a string (it should be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`str.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
if raw_input('Enter a word: ').endswith('s'):
    do_stuff()
```

Or, you can use [Python's Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation):

```
if raw_input('Enter a word: ')[-1:] == 's': # Or you can use [-1]
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: @user2357112: using a slice prevents an IndexError in case of an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.endswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
>>> "fooS".endswith('S')
True
>>> "foob".endswith('S')
False
```

help on `str.endswith`:

```
>>> print str.endswith.__doc__
S.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]]) -> bool

Return True if S ends with the specified suffix, False otherwise.
With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
suffix can also be a tuple of strings to try.
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be treated like lists of characters, and to get the last item of a list you can use `-1`, so after you convert the string to lowercase (just in case you have an uppercase s), your code will look like:

```
if (user_input.lower()[-1] == 's'):
    #Do Stuff
```